# Libgdx FillViewport in main file

Tags: libgdx, scaling

(First i'm french, sorry for the poor english)
I am developping a little game with some friends, one of us code in C++ and I have to code it in Java with Libgdx.

I try to use the FillViewport object out of a stage class, in my main file (which extends ApplicationAdaptater so)

But, when I run my code, nothing is displayed, only the clearcolor of GL.. 
Maybe it's not possible to do it, but if there a solution to do it without using stages (but our own system of interfaces) I take it !

```
public void create () { 
    // Window where we draw
    window = new SpriteBatch();

    // What we see
    windowVisible = new PerspectiveCamera();
    viewport = new FillViewport(Constants.SIZE_X, Constants.SIZE_Y, windowVisible);

    // Starting interface creation
    startingInterface = new StartingInterface();
    startingInterface.launch();

    // Gesture detector | Inputs attach
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this);
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(gestureDetector);
}
```

This is for my initialization. Now this is my render while

```
public void render () {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Camera gestion
    windowVisible.update();
    window.setProjectionMatrix(windowVisible.combined);

    // Display himself
    window.begin();
    startingInterface.display(window);
    window.end();
}
```

Am I doing it wrong ?..

Comment: Why you don't use the Screen class?

Comment: To have a code pretty similar as the C++ code of the project

Comment: PerspectiveCamera for UI, are you doing something in 3D with the interface? You should likely be using an OrthographicCamera for your work with interfaces.

Comment: OrthographicCamera solve the problem, fixed ! Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using OrthographicCamera instead of PerspectiveCamera.
OrthographicCamera for 2D
PerspectiveCamera for 3D